# Error upload .docx with Php?

Tags: php, file

I've uploaded different types of files and I save them in a folder and save into DB the path, all files load them well (.doc, xls ...) except (docx, xlsx ...) . The Docx Files It copies it to the directory but it is not possible to get its name, type size etc.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
if($_POST) {
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "../archivos/" . $nombre;    

    copy($ruta, $destino);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO documentos (tipo,tamano,destino,fecha) VALUES ('$tipo', '$tamanio', '$nombre',NOW())";
    $query = $connect->query($sql);

    $connect->close();

}
```

My form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="../../phpcrud/create_documentos.php" method="POST" id="create_documentos_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="message_create_documentos"></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="apemat" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Archivo</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivo" name="archivo" placeholder="Archivo">
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have the enctype tag in your HTML form? <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Also, you should change if($_POST) to if($_FILES['archivo']['name'])

Comment: ok wait a second

Comment: Does the name of your .docx file contain a single quote, e.g. "Bob's Document.xlsx" - if so then your query will fail. You need to escape the single quote.

Comment: no, just hi.docx

Comment: What happens when you do this 
`$query = $connect->query($sql); if(!$query) { echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect); }`

Comment: consult also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php and make sure the document's are larger than the upload max allowed on your server.